# Making copies of original and changed matrix in R

Tags: r

I've gone through the simple stems of creating a matrix and making changes to a matrix.
However, I want to add a line of code that keeps copies of both matrices. The original and changed.
Example below:

```
t31 <- matrix(seq(1,25, length = 25), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
mean(t31)
t31[t31>23] <- NA
min(t31,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: You could just compute `min(t31[t31 > 23])` without modifying `t31`.

Comment: Make a copy first before changing if you want to keep both `t31_sel <- t31` and make your edit to the copy `t31_sel[t31_sel > 23] <- NA`

Comment: Thanks so much! that worked @thelatemail